# Can I easily implement full text search on a static website on the client side without a database?

Tags: javascript, npm, full-text-search, refactoring, static-site

I found this script somewhere... might have been within npm's source code actually... not sure, all I know is I did not write it myself.. but looking at it I can't help but wonder if it or a similar refactor of the following code could allow a quick web crawl of a static site and return a list of url's that lead to the pages that have the most hits on the search term... I don't need anything fancy like fuzzy search nor am I asking anyone to write the code for me so much as I would like a second (or third) pair of eyes to look at this code and decide if there's any potential in this to implement simple full text search.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const npm = require("./npm.js");
const color = require("ansicolors");
const output = require("./utils/output.js");
const usageUtil = require("./utils/usage.js");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const glob = promisify(require("glob"));
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);
const didYouMean = require("./utils/did-you-mean.js");
const { cmdList } = require("./utils/cmd-list.js");

const usage = usageUtil("help-search", "npm help-search <text>");
const completion = require("./utils/completion/none.js");

const npmUsage = require("./utils/npm-usage.js");

const cmd = (args, cb) =>
  helpSearch(args)
    .then(() => cb())
    .catch(cb);

const helpSearch = async (args) => {
  if (!args.length) throw usage;

  const docPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "docs/content");

  const files = await glob(`${docPath}/*/*.md`);
  const data = await readFiles(files);
  const results = await searchFiles(args, data, files);
  // if only one result, then just show that help section.
  if (results.length === 1) {
    return npm.commands.help([path.basename(results[0].file, ".md")], (er) => {
      if (er) throw er;
    });
  }

  const formatted = formatResults(args, results);
  if (!formatted.trim()) npmUsage(false);
  else {
    output(formatted);
    output(didYouMean(args[0], cmdList));
  }
};

const readFiles = async (files) => {
  const res = {};
  await Promise.all(
    files.map(async (file) => {
      res[file] = (await readFile(file, "utf8"))
        .replace(/^---\n(.*\n)*?---\n/, "")
        .trim();
    })
  );
  return res;
};

const searchFiles = async (args, data, files) => {
  const results = [];
  for (const [file, content] of Object.entries(data)) {
    const lowerCase = content.toLowerCase();
    // skip if no matches at all
    if (!args.some((a) => lowerCase.includes(a.toLowerCase()))) continue;

    const lines = content.split(/\n+/);

    // if a line has a search term, then skip it and the next line.
    // if the next line has a search term, then skip all 3
    // otherwise, set the line to null.  then remove the nulls.
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      const line = lines[i];
      const nextLine = lines[i + 1];
      let match = false;
      if (nextLine) {
        match = args.some((a) =>
          nextLine.toLowerCase().includes(a.toLowerCase())
        );
        if (match) {
          // skip over the next line, and the line after it.
          i += 2;
          continue;
        }
      }

      match = args.some((a) => line.toLowerCase().includes(a.toLowerCase()));

      if (match) {
        // skip over the next line
        i++;
        continue;
      }

      lines[i] = null;
    }

    // now squish any string of nulls into a single null
    const pruned = lines.reduce((l, r) => {
      if (!(r === null && l[l.length - 1] === null)) l.push(r);

      return l;
    }, []);

    if (pruned[pruned.length - 1] === null) pruned.pop();

    if (pruned[0] === null) pruned.shift();

    // now count how many args were found
    const found = {};
    let totalHits = 0;
    for (const line of pruned) {
      for (const arg of args) {
        const hit =
          (line || "").toLowerCase().split(arg.toLowerCase()).length - 1;

        if (hit > 0) {
          found[arg] = (found[arg] || 0) + hit;
          totalHits += hit;
        }
      }
    }

    const cmd = "npm help " + path.basename(file, ".md").replace(/^npm-/, "");
    results.push({
      file,
      cmd,
      lines: pruned,
      found: Object.keys(found),
      hits: found,
      totalHits,
    });
  }

  // sort results by number of results found, then by number of hits
  // then by number of matching lines

  // coverage is ignored here because the contents of results are
  // nondeterministic due to either glob or readFiles or Object.entries
  return results
    .sort(
      /* istanbul ignore next */ (a, b) =>
        a.found.length > b.found.length
          ? -1
          : a.found.length < b.found.length
          ? 1
          : a.totalHits > b.totalHits
          ? -1
          : a.totalHits < b.totalHits
          ? 1
          : a.lines.length > b.lines.length
          ? -1
          : a.lines.length < b.lines.length
          ? 1
          : 0
    )
    .slice(0, 10);
};

const formatResults = (args, results) => {
  const cols = Math.min(process.stdout.columns || Infinity, 80) + 1;

  const out = results
    .map((res) => {
      const out = [res.cmd];
      const r = Object.keys(res.hits)
        .map((k) => `${k}:${res.hits[k]}`)
        .sort((a, b) => (a > b ? 1 : -1))
        .join(" ");

      out.push(
        " ".repeat(Math.max(1, cols - out.join(" ").length - r.length - 1))
      );
      out.push(r);

      if (!npm.flatOptions.long) return out.join("");

      out.unshift("\n\n");
      out.push("\n");
      out.push("-".repeat(cols - 1) + "\n");
      res.lines.forEach((line, i) => {
        if (line === null || i > 3) return;

        if (!npm.color) {
          out.push(line + "\n");
          return;
        }
        const hilitLine = [];
        for (const arg of args) {
          const finder = line.toLowerCase().split(arg.toLowerCase());
          let p = 0;
          for (const f of finder) {
            hilitLine.push(line.substr(p, f.length));
            const word = line.substr(p + f.length, arg.length);
            const hilit = color.bgBlack(color.red(word));
            hilitLine.push(hilit);
            p += f.length + arg.length;
          }
        }
        out.push(hilitLine.join("") + "\n");
      });

      return out.join("");
    })
    .join("\n");

  const finalOut =
    results.length && !npm.flatOptions.long
      ? "Top hits for " +
        args.map(JSON.stringify).join(" ") +
        "\n" +
        "—".repeat(cols - 1) +
        "\n" +
        out +
        "\n" +
        "—".repeat(cols - 1) +
        "\n" +
        "(run with -l or --long to see more context)"
      : out;

  return finalOut.trim();
};

module.exports = Object.assign(cmd, { usage, completion });
```

Comment: I am not married to this script... as a matter of fact I haven't yet taken the time to fully understand it.... It is just serving as a placeholder for the kind of single file solution I have in mind. Obviously if it can return a list of search results in json format than the dom manipulation to display the results would be easy by comparison... no need to elaborate on that part of the process.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your site is structured and generated, I don't see why a client-side text search wouldn't work. I wouldn't recommend crawling the site on the client-side, so it would probably be better to generate a data file at build time, and then basing the search off that.

If your static site is generated with a static site generator, you might be able to get the static site generator to create a JSON file with all the content. Otherwise, if it's just static assets, you could probably create a script to read your content and create the data file that way.

There are also plenty of libraries available that do searching of a JSON object, such as [fuse.js](https://fusejs.io/).

The main concern with a client-side search is the amount of text to search. If you have lots of content, the client would have to load everything into memory, which may be a concern, though you'll have to test things out for your particular use case.